# Cant reference org.osgi.* in plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

Some time ago, I created a project with multiple OSGi plugins. Today I reinstalled [Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/lunasr2), imported the project, and discovered that some errors are occurring in the plugins. Specifically, the `org.osgi.*` path can't be referenced:

[image]

Does anybody know, why this reference errors are occurring and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

The project must be missing the required OSGi core dependencies on its classpath. There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Make sure the project is created as a plugin project, and that the `MANIFEST.MF` exists. There should be a project creation wizard that allows you to create the project as an Eclipse plugin.
2. If you use Maven in your project, the best way to manage your RCP projects is to use [Tycho](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html). It helps automatically resolving plugin dependencies and building your project (even from the command line) and is a much better solution for the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the target platform setup. This is where plugin projects get their build time dependencies from.